# Show that $\mathcal{M} \models \sigma(\vec{a})$ if and only if $\mathcal{M} \models \sigma(\vec{b})$.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

So I have this question 
Let $\sigma$ be a sentence in a language $L, \mathcal{M}$ an $L$ -structure, and $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$ infinite tuples from $M .$ Show that $\mathcal{M} \models \sigma(\vec{a})$ if and only if $\mathcal{M} \models \sigma(\vec{b})$.

I don't know how to approach this question. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: oh @AlexKruckman, I think the point is probably that $\sigma$ is a sentence, not a general formula

Comment: Oh, upon reading more carefully, I see what the intention is. The point is that since $\sigma$ is a sentence, the values of $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$ are irrelevant! The statement uses a notational convention that I have always found rather  confusing...

Comment: Yes exactly. Since it is a sentence, it has no free variable so I can write it as $\mathcal{M} \models \sigma$ . Because $\mathcal{M} \models  \sigma(\vec{a})$ depends only on the i^th coordinates of $\vec{a}$  if i^th variable is free. But  I don't know how to write it properly

Comment: @daisy does the notation $\sigma(\bar{a})$ mean the sentence obtained by replacing every free occurrence of the variable $v_i$ in $\sigma$ with $a_i$? if so you can argue that $\sigma$ has no free variables, so $\sigma(\bar{a})$ is identical to $\sigma(\bar{b})$, as there are no substitutions made in either

Comment: yes it is what I understand too

Comment: what you've said in your comment is exactly right! :) ... $\sigma(\bar{a})$ will depend on $a_i$ only if $v_i$ appears freely in $\sigma$. since $\sigma$ has *no* free variables, $\sigma(\bar{a})$ therefore does not depend on any values in the tuple $\bar{a}$. I don't know what level of formality your instruction is expecting, but that should be enough to write for a solution! you might want to add that $\sigma(\bar{a})$ and $\sigma(\bar{b})$ are thus "syntatically" equal; ie, they are actually identical sentences

Comment: well, what's the formal definition of $\sigma(\bar{a})$ that you've been given?

Comment: Actually the formal definition is what you said in your comment. So you're right,  there might be no need for extra explanation. Thank you for your help:)